# Avatar portrait image generator

Tags: image-editor

I'm looking for an avatar portrait image generator, that

- has (at least one) professional, polished drawing style
- has enough settings to create a comic portrait, that looks similar to the real person
- has no significant usage license limitations for the resulting images
- should at least provide an output size of 64 x 64 pixel or
- *optionally* can export to SVG
- *optionally* may process a given photo for initial feature recognition

Recommendations about a Windows, Android or web application or even a software library are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Faceyourmanga](http://www.faceyourmanga.com)** is a website that offers a service to create manga style portrait suitable for use as online avatars.

**Pros:**

- It has (one) polished style
- It has many categories of options like:

  1. Person customisation: chin, eyes, mouth, hair style etc.
  2. Clothing customisation: shirt, jacket, ties, scarves, accessories
  3. Backdrop customisation: flat, pattern, location
  4. Most options allow customisation of colour.
- The resulting images are provided under this [license](http://www.faceyourmanga.com/page.php?id=terms). Notably:

  1. Attribution: User must attribute the work in the manner specified by the author; (*No other mention of Attribution appears on this page?!?)*
  2. Non Commercial: User can't use the work for direct or indirect commercial purpose. For indirect commercial purpose it's meant also an use of the work as an instrument for criticism to teaching, discussion, and/or news broadcasted (TV, cinema, newspapers) with a clear commercial purpose.
  3. No derivative works: User can't modify or transform this work, nor use it to make another one.
- When avatar creation is complete:

  1. For unregistered users a link to the download page will be sent via email.  This download page will provide a 180x180 pixel png file
  2. Registered users can save to and then manage a gallery of avatars

**Cons:**

- Despite the user interface being Flash based it will not export to a vector format.
- It does not offer any ability to analyse your photos to recognise features.

Here is a sample of possible output, the first is hand selected, the later two are random:
[image][image][image]

Note: They also have native applications for iOS, but I have not used this software and am unable to comment on its quality.